# convert complex numbers in the form a+bi

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

so the question states Convert the following in the form $a + bi$

$i^{131}$

I have never seen such a question like this before and it is confusing me on how to compute this. I understand that $i^2 = -1$, but this is to the power of 131.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we know that $i^2=-1$

Now, we have

$$i^{131}=i^{2\cdot 65+1}=(i^2)^{65}\cdot i=(-1)^{65}\cdot i=-i=\color{red}{0-i}$$

Answer (score 1):

$i^{131} = i^{2\cdot 65 + 1} = (i^2)^{35}\cdot i = (-1)^{35}\cdot i = (-1)\cdot i = -i.$

A good observation is $i^4 = 1$ so $i^{4n + k} = i^k$.  If $k = 1$, then $i$, if $k = 2$ than $-1$, if $k = 3$ than $-i$, if $k = 0$ than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $i^{131}=\frac{i^{132}}{i}=\frac{1}{i}=-i$.

Comment: How would the OP know that $i^{132}$ = 1?

Comment: $i^2=-1$ implies $i^4=1$ and so $i^{132}=(i^4)^{33}=1^{33}=1.$

Comment: But the OP didn't realize that.  That's why the question was asked.